# How to move the files to new directory based on names in text file?

Tags: linux, files, filenames, text, move

I have `tar.gz` files like below in a directory `df`:

```
A.tar.gz
B.tar.gz
C.tar.gz
D.tar.gz
E.tar.gz
F.tar.gz
G.tar.gz
```

I also have text file `move.txt` with following columns information:

```
ID  Status      Status2     Status3     Status4     Status5         tar   sample
ID1 Negative    Negative    Negative    Negative    Negative    D.tar.gz    Sam1
ID2 Negative    Negative    Negative    Negative    Negative    A.tar.gz    Sam2
ID3 Negative    Negative    Negative    Negative    Negative    C.tar.gz    Sam3
ID4 Negative    Negative    Negative    Negative    Negative    F.tar.gz    Sam4
```

I want to move files in directory `df` to another directory based on their matching in `move.txt` file

I tried this way but didn't work:

```
for file in $(cat move.txt)
do 
    mv "$file" ~/destination 
done
```

Output should be in `~/destination` directory:

```
D.tar.gz
A.tar.gz
C.tar.gz
F.tar.gz
```

Looks like I'm missing the column in the text file. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`bash`** + **`awk`** solution:

```
for f in $(awk 'NR > 1{ print $7 }' move.txt); do 
    [[ -f "$f" ]] && mv "$f" ~/destination
done
```

---

Or with `xargs`:

```
awk 'NR > 1{ print $7 }' move.txt | xargs -I {} echo mv {} ~/destination
```

---

The crucial `awk` operation implies:

- `NR > 1` - start processing from the 2nd line (skip the 1st one as *header*)
- `print $7` - print the 7th field value `$7` (`tar` column)

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question

Inside directory "df" I gave the following command. And it worked.

```
cat move.txt | xargs mv -t destination/
```